# How to compare these two dates?

Tags: java, javascript

What's the best way to compare a Java date with Javascript date for greater than or less than comparison?

Java date format: `1985-01-01T00:00:00.000-06:00`

Javascript date format: `Tue Jan 29 1980 00:00:00 GMT-0600`

Comment: In what context?  Do you have the two timestamps stored as strings in your JavaScript or Java appliation?  Or do you just want to compare them manually?

Comment: Hi cheeken, first date is coming as String and the second one is a Date object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two date objects, you can compare them directly:

```
var date0 = new Date(2012,0,1); // 1 Jan 2012
var date1 = new Date(2012,1,1); // 1 Feb 2012

if (date0 < date1)  { /* true */ }
```

Otherwise, if both dates are ISO8601 dates in the same time zone, you can compare them as strings:

```
var date0 = '2012-01-01T00:00:00.000';
var date1 = '2012-02-01T00:00:00.000';

if (date0 < date1)  { /* true */ }
```

Answer (score 3):

Both Java and Javascript `Date` objects have a `getTime` method, that returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch. Ideally, you'd send the date from Java in that format rather than as a string.

Failing that, you could parse it in Javascript with something like [this](https://github.com/csnover/js-iso8601) to convert it to a `Date`, and then compare to the other as normal (modern browsers will be able to handle ISO 8601 out of the box, but notably IE 8 or lower won't).

Comment: @DhaivatPandya Why do you say they suck?

Comment: Cant call getTime on Java Date as its coming to me as a String already.